# Different method for creating unique output

Tags: python, function, file, file-io

Problem:
Using infile and outfile i am trying to write to the outfile unique words and frequency for each line within the infile. As an example, given 'one fish two fish' the output would be one:1 two:1 fish:2 (order doesn't matter.) I was able to successfully do this, but using something that wasn't taught in my class. Which is the set function, which automatically takes the unique words of a list.

My Question:
Is there any other method of achieving the same output without overly complicating the problem? I thought maybe appending words to a list but i couldn't get it to work. Any and all help is appreciated!

My working code using set function.

```
def wordsByLine(inFile,outFile):
    inF=open(inFile,'r')
    outF=open(outFile,'w')
    for line in inF:
        wordlst=line.split()
        uniquewordlst=set(wordlst)
        for word in uniquewordlst:
            outF.write(word+':'+str(line.count(word))+' ')
        outF.write('\n')
    outF.close()
    inF.close()
wordsByLine('fish.txt','fishWords.txt')
```

InFile:

> one fish two fish
>
> red fish blue fish

OutFile:

> fish:2 one:1 two:1
>
> fish:2 red:1 blue:1

Answer (score 0):

you could use counter as shown below. Instead of a file, I use a list, but it should hold true to each line in file

```
a = ['one fish two fish','red fish blue fish']
from collections import Counter
for i in a:
    print ["{0}:{1}".format(i,j) for i,j in  Counter(i.split()).most_common()]
```

results in

```
['fish:2', 'two:1', 'one:1']
['fish:2', 'blue:1', 'red:1']
```

you can write this output to a file

Answer (score 0):

to get a dictionary of words and their frequencies

```
aa = 'one fish two fish'
bb = aa.split(' ')
cc = {x:bb.count(x) for x in bb}

>>> cc
{'fish': 2, 'two': 1, 'one': 1}
```